# Combining year & month as an integer or an object while ignoring nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and am working with pandas.
The dataframe has many columns and some of them are in datetime format:

```
id       calv1       calv2
1   2006-08-29  2007-08-29
2          NaT         NaT
3   2006-08-29         NaT
4   2006-08-29  2007-08-29
5   2006-08-29  2013-08-29
6   2006-08-29         NaT
```

I am trying to make a new columns where I use the year and month from the datetime columns and combine them to an integer or a string. And I want to ignore the Nat/nan values so either a none/nan value or just a zero for those values.

```
id       calv1       calv2     YM1     YM2
1   2006-08-29  2007-08-29  200608  200708
2          NaT         NaT       0       0
3   2006-08-29         NaT  200608       0
4   2006-08-29  2007-08-29  200608  200708  
5   2006-08-29  2013-08-29  200608  201308  
6   2006-08-29         NaT  200608       0
```

This is what I've tried:

```
df['YM1'] = ((pd.DatetimeIndex(df['calv1']).year).astype(str) +
   (pd.DatetimeIndex(df['calv1']).month).astype(str))
```

and:

```
df['YM1'] = (((df['calv1']).dt.year).astype(str) +
   ((df['calv1']).dt.month).astype(str))
```

But this the values in the output columns look like this:

```
2014.011.0
```

or

```
2014.09.0
```

And ofcourse the NaT values come out as

```
 nannan
```

Any ideas how to approach this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `df['YM1'] = ((pd.DatetimeIndex(df['calv1']).year).astype(int)*100 + (pd.DatetimeIndex(df['calv1']).month).astype(int))`?

Comment: Love the simple idea, doesn't work if I still have NaT/Nan values because they can't be converted to integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the date as year month with `.dt.strftime` and `%Y%m`, then you can convert it to `int`. For column `calv1`, e.g:

```
df.calv1.dt.strftime('%Y%m').fillna(0).astype(int)

0    200608
1         0
2    200608
3    200608
4    200608
5    200608
Name: calv1, dtype: int32
```

Assign it back to the data frame:

```
df[['YM1', 'YM2']] = df[['calv1', 'calv2']].apply(
    lambda s: s.dt.strftime('%Y%m').fillna(0).astype(int)
)

df
   id      calv1      calv2     YM1     YM2
0   1 2006-08-29 2007-08-29  200608  200708
1   2        NaT        NaT       0       0
2   3 2006-08-29        NaT  200608       0
3   4 2006-08-29 2007-08-29  200608  200708
4   5 2006-08-29 2013-08-29  200608  201308
5   6 2006-08-29        NaT  200608       0
```

Comment: When I try this for one column in my dataframe I get this error

`ValueError: ("invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NaT'", 'occurred at index calv1')`

Comment: It seems you have `NaT` as strings. Have you converted `calv1` column to `datetime` ? `df.calv1 = pd.to_datetime(df.calv1)`

Comment: Column is datetime64[ns] before I insert this code. If I change `.astype(int)` to `.astype(str)` it works. Except it changes the Nat to strings so the fillna(0) does not work.

Comment: We might be using a different pandas version. Try `df.calv1.dt.strftime('%Y%m').replace('NaT', '0').astype(int)`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try:

1. filter the required columns
2. convert them to the required format
3. change the column names
4. concat the result with the original df.

```
df1 = df.filter(like='calv').apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%Y%m')).fillna(0)
df1.columns = ['YM' + col.strip('calv') for col in df1.columns]
df = pd.concat([df, df1], 1)
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
  id      calv1      calv2     YM1     YM2
0   1 2006-08-29 2007-08-29  200608  200708
1   2        NaT        NaT       0       0
2   3 2006-08-29        NaT  200608       0
3   4 2006-08-29 2007-08-29  200608  200708
4   5 2006-08-29 2013-08-29  200608  201308
5   6 2006-08-29        NaT  200608       0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do this without applying to the dataframe

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
       'calv1': [dt(2006,8,29), np.nan, dt(2006,8,29),dt(2006,8,29),dt(2006,8,29),dt(2006,8,29)],
       'calv2': [dt(2007,8,29), np.nan, np.nan, dt(2007,8,29), dt(2013,8,29), np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['YM1'] = (df['calv1'].dt.year.astype(str).str.strip('.0') 
             + '0' 
             + df['calv1'].dt.month.astype(str).str.strip('.0')
            ).where(df['calv1'].notnull())

df['YM2'] = (df['calv2'].dt.year.astype(str).str.strip('.0') 
             + '0' 
             + df['calv2'].dt.month.astype(str).str.strip('.0')
            ).where(df['calv2'].notnull())
```

outputs

```
    id    calv1       calv2       YM1     YM2
0   1   2006-08-29  2007-08-29  200608  200708
1   2      NaT         NaT        NaN     NaN
2   3   2006-08-29     NaT      200608    NaN
3   4   2006-08-29  2007-08-29  200608  200708
4   5   2006-08-29  2013-08-29  200608  201308
5   6   2006-08-29     NaT      200608    NaN
```

For large datasets this will be faster.